# Documentation Bug? FB Graph API explorer cannot return /me/address

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am playing FB graph API explorer which is a fantastic tool to test graph API. But I met a weird case.

First of all, I have a access token with all permissions to access myself account. 
Here is my query:

```
me?fields=id,name,address
```

But I only got:

```
{
  "id": "alongnumber", 
  "name": "stringname"
}
```

Where is "address" returned?

Thanks

Derek

@Tobi suggests it might be a documentation bug. Can anyone confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such field as `address`. Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

to see which fields are currently available. To get the current location, you can use `me?fields=id,location{id}`, and then request the `location.id` object in a second request to get the location details.

Comment: In "field" table, the 3rd row, isn't it "address"? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Hm, true, but this shouldn't be there I guess. I think it's a documentation bug.

Comment: Then do you know what is the correct way to get the current city and state?

Comment: I opened a bug with FB yesterday to let them verify this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1596438277293485/ Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

There is no field like `Address` though there is `current_address` & `current_location` but they also don't seem to work with basic permissions.

Check this for all the field names which you can get from the API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user#columns

Comment: I am using graph API 2.3 while you are talking about version 2.0. we are not on the same page. Latest User fields are described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user Also, if you read carefully, I have stated that I "have a access token with all permissions".